# get all records on a page of a db table typo3 4.6.1

Tags: php, typo3

I need all records for a page, but i need it to work for the specific language and workspace that the user is currently in.

In traditional typo3 i used something like:

```
        $query = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTgetRows(
            '*',         // SELECT ...
            'tx_faqs_domain_model_faqsections',     // FROM ...
            'pid=' . (int) $pid . ' and deleted=0 and hidden=0 and sys_language_uid=' . $lang . ' AND t3ver_wsid = ' . (int) $workspace,    // WHERE...
            '',            // GROUP BY...
            'sorting',    // ORDER BY...
            ''            // LIMIT ...
        ); 
    foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = utf8_encode($value); 
    }
```

However, the following doesn't work with workspaces and doesn't seem to fit with the new flow3 framework.

I had a look at doing:

```
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    return $query->execute();
```

inside my Tx_Faqs_Domain_Repository_FaqSectionsRepository class but this returns an empty array.

An example of getting all records for a particular page, in a particular workspace, for a particular language from a db table would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method to your repository which does the filtering for you:

```
public function findAllFromPage(){
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);

    $pid = intval($GLOBALS['TSFE']->id);
    $query->matching($query->equals('pid',$pid ));
    return $query->execute();
}
```

The important bit is, that you set `respectStoragePage` to false, otherwise it's just looking for the entries in your configured storage pid (That's also the reason why a magic function like `findByPid($GLOBALS['TSFE']->id);`, which is available in the repository class anyway,  won't work)